# when I use Cocoapods install both objective-c and swift libs, then build error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

For test, I create a new project named "test"
I want import two libraries "Popmenu(oc lib)" and "Alamofire(swift lib)" by Cocoapods.
the Podfile below:

```
target 'test' do

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'PopMenu'
end
```

and I used `pod install` cmd install successfully.

but when I build it, it caused some problem like this:

> /Users/piqiu1/Desktop/test/Pods/PopMenu/PopMenu/PopMenu.m:11:9: 'XHRealTimeBlur.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
>
> /Users/piqiu1/Desktop/test/Pods/PopMenu/PopMenu/PopMenu.m:12:9: 'POP.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
>
> /Users/piqiu1/Desktop/test/Pods/PopMenu/PopMenu/MenuButton.m:10:9: 'POP.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead

who can tell me what will do?

Comment: Did you open the generated workspace project after successful installation of the cocoapods ? or your previous project ?

Comment: yes, I do it like you say

Comment: @benjamin.wu did you solve this?